How to use secomp profile without putting file in /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/profiles in k8s
I am looking for solution where i want to use seccomp profile in my pod without configuring the profile json in /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/profiles.
Firstly Is it even possible?
I checked with GPT , it is suggesting me like below :D
    securityContext:
      seccompProfile:
        type: Localhost
        localhostProfile: |
          {
            "defaultAction": "SCMP_ACT_ALLOW",
            "architectures": [
              "SCMP_ARCH_X86_64"
            ],
            "syscalls": [
              {
                "names": [
                  "ptrace",
                  "openat"
                ],
                "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO"
              }
            ]
          }

But it is not working and expecting the local profile to be available in  /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/profiles folder.
Any suggestion?

Since this post is not about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic for [sf] or DevOps.

If you want to use the seccomp profile in your pod without configuring the profile json in /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/profiles you may use RuntimeDefault seccomp profile.
As per this Official Kubernetes document :

Most container runtimes provide a sane set of default syscalls that are allowed or not. You can adopt these defaults for your workload by setting the seccomp type in the security context of a pod or container to RuntimeDefault.
Note: If you have the seccompDefault configuration enabled, then Pods use the RuntimeDefault seccomp profile whenever no other seccomp profile is specified. Otherwise, the default is Unconfined.
Here's a manifest for a Pod that requests the RuntimeDefault seccomp profile for all its containers:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: default-pod
  labels:
    app: default-pod
spec:
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: hashicorp/http-echo:1.0
    args:
    - "-text=just made some more syscalls!"
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false


Refer to this document and also check this blog for more information which might be helpful for you.

Hello Pranay, Thanks for your reply. Yes, RuntimeDefault is possible but i am looking that i can provide custom profile someshow without adding into the node kubelet location. I want to restrict container to perform ptrace syscall.
